# Is it possible to detect changes in Azure role instance count using events only?

Tags: c#, events, azure

In my Azure role I need to be able to query the current number of instances at any time.

I don't have any internal endpoints, so I can't use [Role.Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.role.instances.aspx). I can use Management API, but it's relatively time consuming and querying it sometimes results in protocol timeout errors and I'd prefer to not deal with timeouts.

Looks like there's [RoleEnvironment.Changing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) event that can contain `RoleEnvironmentTopologyChange` class objects that reflects which role changes the instance count. This would be optimal for me - I wouldn't need to do any external calls, just store the new instance count when it changes, so no overhead and no timeouts. Yet I can't find whether it's possible to find the new instance count when `RoleEnvironment.Changing` fires.

Is it possible to detect the changes in role instance count and the actual number of instances using only `RoleEnvironment.Changing` or similar events in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, inside that event handler, you can use RoleEnvironment.Roles to obtain a list of roles. Then for each role, you can use the Instances property to find how many instances does that role have. It is not needed to use management API. To detect change, query instance count during the instance's startup, and save the data in memory, so you can compare it later.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: `Role.Instances` only works if the role has internal endpoints and that's not my case as specified in the question.

Comment: Yes, at least one internal endpoint must be defined for a role to enable instances to be known at runtime, please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.roles.aspx to see whether it helps

Comment: I've read that before asking the question and I don't have internal endpoints.